# OCMock EXC_BAD_ACCESS when stubbing block

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, ocmock

I am trying to use OCMock's andDo with a block but every time I try it, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Below is an example with NSNotificationCenter but I get the same result for other objects using blocks.

What am I missing?

```
[[[notificationCenterMock stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {

        void (^block)(NSNotification *note);
        [invocation getArgument:&block atIndex:2];

        NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

        block(notification); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling this line

    }] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil queue:[OCMArg any] usingBlock:[OCMArg any]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into this too deeply, and without seeing more code, I think you might have to use `__unsafe_unretained` on the `block` variable. See here for more: [EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing parameters in andDo of OCMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268502/exc-bad-access-when-accessing-parameters-in-anddo-of-ocmock)

Comment: Same problem with __unsafe_unretained. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try telling the invocation to retain its arguments:

```
[[[notificationCenterMock stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    [invocation retainArguments];

    void (^block)(NSNotification *note);
    [invocation getArgument:&block atIndex:2];
    // …
```